# How can I set a composite primary key in my migration file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, composite-primary-key

migration file:

```
class CreateMyRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table my_records:, :primary_key =>:partner_id do |t|
      t.integer :partner_id, references: [:Partner, :partnerID]
      t.integer :client_id, references: [:Client, :id]
    end
  end
end
```

How can I make partner_id and client_id a composite primary key?
thank u!

Comment: You possibly don't need to, have a read of this similar question and see if the `:through` association described in the answer suits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074206/give-composite-primary-key-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague gave me his answer and I think is't right, thanks for Sachin R & Matt any way:

```
create_table :my_records, id: false do |t|
  t.integer :partner_id, references: [:Partner, :partnerID]
  t.integer :client_id, references: [:Client, :id]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You not need to add compoiste primary key on migration. You can define composite primary key columns on your model by using `composite_primary_keys` gem http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/

Comment: but only adding a composite primary key on migration can make this composite key into database, isn't it?